# Fiddler unable to send client certificate

Tags: http, https, fiddler, client-certificates, pki

I am using **PKI** for my web application. From the browser i am able to select the client certificate and  website is working fine.
I want to debug our website through **Fiddler**. But through fiddler i am unable to send the **client certificate** to server.
I modified fillder's CustomeRules.js file as below.

```
 static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
     oSession["https-Client-Certificate"] = "E:\\Cer\\AuthCer.cer";
//Other Code....
    }
```

But still no change. I am getting below error in chrome

> **This site can’t be reached**